# Aggregated entity reference translation

Tags: entities

I'm having two customs content types in D7, one row (A) and another (B) that aggregates (via entity reference) the rows into bundles of rows (e.g. tables).

I can have up to 40 rows in a table. I'm translating manually each row in several languages. 
And then I'm creating one node (lets say node 100) in English of type B aggregating the 40 rows (let's say nodes 1-40) in English, and another node 101 in French (a translation of the English  node 100) that aggregates the nodes 41-80 which are a direct translation of the 1-40 rows.

I would like while adding node 101 in French as a translation of node 100(English) to already pre-fill the node 101 to aggregate the nodes 41-80 which are in french and a one to one translation of the 1-40 English row nodes.

The translated entity reference module cannot help me in my case.

I tried to find a hook for the "add translation" to prepopulate the screen where the node 101 is being created as a translation of the node 100, and then just having to fill in 1-2 other extra fields in French and save...

Now I have to find the 41-80 references by hand, and since I'm having several languages (5 currently) the work involved is immense...

How could I achieve what I need? is there a module already written? otherwise which hook shall I use? I couldn't find an add translation hook in D7 (I believe there might be one in D8).
I just need to know which hook to use for adding a new translation, I think I can manage the rest (finding for each row the translation in the target language).

I also do not need to do anything upon editing the node 101 after it has been saved, thus I only need the hook used the first time the node 101 is being created as a translation of node 100.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the hook_node_prepare($node) and there to check 
     if (!empty($node->translation_source))

The above are the conditions that must be filled in to be in the "add translation" event.